# Sql anywhere 12 connection string

Tags: sqlanywhere

I am trying to connect  sql anywhere12 database to my .net project but while connecting to the database i am facing an error

"{"Invalid connection string. Error parsing connection parameter string\r\nParameter name: connectionString"}"

while running this code.

```
private void btncon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         string connetionString = null;
            SAConnection connection;
            SACommand command;
            string sqla = null;

           // connetionString = "Data Source=SQL Anywhere 12 Demo;Initial Catalog=Demo2;User ID=dba;Password=sql";
            connetionString = "Driver={SQL Anywhere 12};ENG=demo12;UID=dba;PWD=sql;DBN=sql;LINKS=TCPIP(HOST=localhost)";

            sqla = "INSERT INTO  student(Rollnumber,Name) values('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "')";

            connection = new SAConnection(connetionString);
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                command = new SACommand(sqla, connection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                command.Dispose();
                connection.Close();
                MessageBox.Show(" ExecuteNonQuery in SqlCommand executed !!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
            }

        }
```

actually i have no much  knowledge about the sql anywhere 12 connection string please  help me to solve this error

Comment: try this:
connetionString = "ENG=demo12;UID=dba;PWD=sql;DBN=sql;LINKS=TCPIP";

Comment: thank you so much its working